# Why won't visual studio include a file in publish output?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Strangely this issue only affects a single file which we will call test.lic.  test.lic is an xml file and is located in the root folder of an asp.net mvc project.

The file properties are:

```
Build Action = "Content"
Copy To Output Directory = "Never"
```

Other files in the root folder with the same settings (i.e. robot.txt) are included in the publish output.  Changing Copy to Output Directory seems to have no effect

Comment: What do you get if you set your build output verbosity to diagnostic?

Comment: Is the Copy Local property set to True?

Comment: Does it get published to the `/bin` folder by chance?

Comment: @AnanthanUnni AFAIK Copy Local is only for references.  This isn't a reference is is an xml file (license file in xml format).

Comment: @mxmissile it does not get published to bin, although this isn't unexpected as CopyToOutput is set to false.  It appear that although the file has a build action of Content, MSBuild is ignoring that setting. I set BuildAction to NONE and CopyToOutput to true.  This copied the file to bin folder and I updated reference so that provides a workaround but I am still unsure why VS/MSbuild is ignoring the setting.

Comment: @Greg Set build output to diagnostic and I don't see anything unexpected but it is a large solution so we are talking 10,000+ lines.  In the final stage "publishing folder /..." it has all the other root level files but not this .lic file.  Searching for the filename it appears in prior steps so it would appear something (maybe undocumented feature) is stripping the file from final publish (something that is not done to other files w/ same properties BuildAction:Content CopyToOutputFolder: false)